# Kendo UI Core vs Kendo UI Web

Tags: kendo-ui

What is difference between Kendo UI Web and Kendo UI Core

https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoUIWeb

http://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoUICore/

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kendo UI Core is free and open source; however, it only includes 40 out of the 70 widgets and you get no support from Telerik. *[Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui-core)*.

Kendo UI Web is their professional suite (I assume) and includes all 70 widgets, but should only be used on a 30-day trial. It is not licensed open source, so, there's your fair warning. *[Kendo UI Professional](http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui)*.

Also, it's not easy to tell via NuGet what you're really getting, so be mindful.

Comment: Indeed, Kendo UI Core and Kendo UI components get different levels of support from Telerik, here's their help page on this: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/list-of-widgets.

Answer (score 6):

I could be wrong, but I believe that Kendo UI Core is the open source version of Kendo UI. It has less features in it than Kendo UI Web, which requires a commercial licence but also grants dedicated support.